# Issue with Data Protection on Capabilities tab

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I have enabled `Data Protection` for my iOS application and set `Protected Until First User Authentication` mode. Here is screenshot from my App ID:
[image: App ID setting]

I also set this in my `entitlements` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.default-data-protection</key>
    <string>NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

However, xcode constantly shows issue on `Capabilities` tab: 
[image: Data Protection issue]

When I click `Fix Issue` it modifies my `entitlements` file and sets: `NSFileProtectionComplete` which is different than App ID setting, so then I get errors on `General` tab under each provisioning profile (I have disabled `Automatically manage signing`).

I can't get rid off this issue. However everything seems to work, I can build it without any issues. Any ideas how to fix it?

`Bundle identifier` is correct and provisioning profiles are set properly. I'm using Xcode 10.2.